# CSS 3 columns, why is the third column taking over the other 2?

Tags: css

Here is the smallest amount of code that clearly illustrates my problem:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div style="float: left; width: 200px;">One</div>
    <div style="float: left; width: 200px;">Two</div>
    <div style="background-color: #f0f;">Three</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The first 2 divs are supposed to be 2 left columns.  The 3rd should take up the rest of the page.  Eventually, I'm going to add options to hide and show the 2 columns on the left.

But, why is the color purple extending all the way to the browser's left edge?  I am trying to get it to start at the word "Three".

Comment: http://doctype.com/ might be more suitable for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to 'float' the third column as well. Then add a clearing block after it.

Comment: The third column won't take up the rest of the page if made a float.

Comment: sorry - missed that part of the question. If you know the width of your page, then just set a width on the third column, and adjust the width when hiding your other columns. If you need the third column to expand to fit the browser window, no matter what the width is, you may need to use a table.

Comment: No need for table, use `overflow: hidden` as told in my answer.

Comment: I see that your answer allows the expansion of the third column, which is cool. The OP said that he will need to show/hide the left 2 columns, which means that the padding on the container div will be wrong if either or both of them are hidden. He will need to use script to adjust the numbers. If he ever needs dynamic sizing of either of the left columns, this will get even more complicated, and then may require a table.

Comment: Yaggo, you had a great answer.  In this particular case, the table is the way that I went because I needed it to not wrap, but not hide the overflow, either.

Answer (score 1):

See [Block formatting contexts](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting) by W3C:

> In a block formatting context, each box's left outer edge touches the left edge of the containing block (for right-to-left formatting, right edges touch). This is true even in the presence of floats (although a box's line boxes may shrink due to the floats), unless the box establishes a new block formatting context (in which case the box itself may become narrower due to the floats).

You can avoid that by forcing creation of new blocking formatting context:

```
<div style="background-color: #f0f; overflow: hidden">Three</div>
```

If `overflow: hidden` is not an option for you (popups etc.), here is another technique:

```
<div class="has-columns">
    <div class="column first">...</div>
    <div class="column second">...</div>
    <div class="column third">...</div>
</div>
```

```
.has-columns {
    padding-left: 400px; /* padding reserved for floats */
}

.column.first {
    width: 180px;
    margin-left: -400px;
    float: left;
}

.column.second {
    width: 180px;
    margin-left: -200px;
    float: left;
}
```

I have to admit, the behavior of floats can be confusing sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Depending what you want to have happen when columns one and two disappear, you have a few options:

1) If you want column 3 to expand and fill all the remaining space simply add `overflow: hidden;` to the styles of the third div. It will flow next to the two floated divs just as you expect.

2) If you want the third column to keep it's size and shape no matter what happens to columns 1 and 2, float it to the right, with a set width such as `float: right; width: 200px;` and it will no longer be effected by the other two, but stay 200px at the right edge of the container.